# How to add text file in cucumber extent report

Tags: selenium, cucumberjs

I'm generating cucumber extents report with screenshot attached to the result , but now I want to add a text file to the output file, is it possible? if yes can you please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Create and add a link to the text file:

```
test.info("<a href='path/text-file.txt'>click to view text</a>");
```

Comment: similary is their a way to add files for cucumber reports ? as of now i am seeing we can add screenshots , but haven't seen article which tells to add file or Json's to the cucumber reports.

Comment: Cucumber version? @Rahul

Comment: @foursth : Cucumber Java version is 1.2.5

Comment: I am not sure how.. I would recommend checking in the Extent Cucumber Plugin created by Vimal.

Comment: Yes using that it is possible , but explicitly looking for cucumber reports plugin from jenkins..

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add a text along with the report? If so, it is simple by just adding the text that you want to provide in `this.attach()`

e.g: - `this.attach('Hello');`

```
After(function (scenarioResult) {
        if(scenarioResult.isFailed()){
            try {
                let failedStep = '';
                scenarioResult.stepResults.map((stepResult) => {
                    if(stepResult.status === Status.FAILED){
                        failedStep = stepResult.step.name;
                    }
                });
               this.scenario.attach(JSON.stringify(report, ["name", "age"], '\t'));
               //where name and age are keys in the json report
               return this.attach('Failed scenario is ' + scenarioResult.scenario.name + ' - ' + failedStep);

            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: similary is their a way to add files for cucumber reports ? as of now i am seeing we can add screenshots , but haven't seen article which tells to add file or Json's to the cucumber reports.

Comment: I think there are ways to add json string/text to report. Else you can also give a link to the file as a href in this.attach

Comment: Updated the previous answer with attaching json to report

Comment: why am not seeing attach method in scenario ? i parameterize my after scenario method with Scenario scenario , but when i try to find the attach method in scenario , its not their , what might be the reason ?

Comment: @After()
 public void tearDown(Scenario scenario)
 {
  scenario.attach 
  
  // not able to find attach method
 }

Comment: The example that I posted using Cucumber js, and I could see attach function in it. If you are using java, I assume there will be a similar utility - probably embed. Can you check with embed method